# How to conditionally use wrapping blocks in groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the current piece of Groovy (Jenkins DSL flavor) and I want to make the wrapping blocks optional.

```
timestamps {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            sh cmd
        }
    }
```

New functionality:

```
def use_timestamps = true // or false
def use_ansiColor = false // or true

/* some code to run the `sh cmd` with or without blocks */
```

PS. I know that I could make it work with two sets of if blocks but it will look very-very ugly and I want to avoid that. If a new wrapper is added it could become a nightmare.

Answer (score 6):

There is no generic solution that will work for arbitrary wrappers.  The if blocks you mention will be required in some form to achieve what you want.

However, you can improve matters somewhat by making the conditionals into methods.

```
def use_timestamps = true // or false
def use_ansiColor = false // or true


timestampsOptional(use_timestamps) {
    ansiColorOptional(use_ansiColor, 'xterm') {
        sh cmd
    }
}

def timestampsOptional(active, Closure action) {
    if (active) {
        timestamps action
    } else {
        action()
    }    
}

def ansiColorOptional(active, encoding, Closure action) {
    if (active) {
        ansiColor(encoding) action
    } else {
        action()
    }    
}
```

The methods could then be moved into a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/),
keeping the ugliness out of your `Jenkinsfile` and allowing them to be reused by other Pipelines.

Comment: Does this technique work if the wrapper takes parameters? E.g. `gitlabBuilds[builds: ["Checkout", "Build", "Report"]) { ... }` - will those parameters be automatically bundled into `Closure action`? Or will the method need to provide the parameters itself?

Comment: To answer myself, turns out this can be written as ```def gitlabBuildsOptional(enable, builds, Closure action) {
    if (enable) {
        gitlabBuilds(builds: builds, action)
    } else {
        action()
    }
}```